# TYPO3 Extbase FE form - how to remove/delete inline relation

Tags: frontend, typo3, extbase

I have a complex custom Extbase Database on which I am doing a frontend (FE) editor with subtables. With the propertyMappingConfiguration allowCreationForSubProperty I was able to implement an easy way for the user to add new sub-records in M:n relation.

Now my question is how can I implement a deletion of those records? Simply removing the properties from the FORM (in my case removing tx_jobfinder_jobanzeige[jobanzeige][sprachkenntnisse][2][niveau]) from the html-form does obviously not trigger a delete event for this sub-table entry.

Is there a way to automatically trigger it via extbase? How would I implement that?
Setting tx_jobfinder_jobanzeige[jobanzeige][sprachkenntnisse][2] to null or how would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is struggling with the same problem or asks how this is done. I found the hidden problem. In the edit-form the user can remove such a connection and via javascript I remove the selects BUT you also have to remove the hidden field [__identity] - then via cascade Extbase automatically updates the object and all will be saved correctly.